# Text/object manipulation using 3js or other platforms

Tags: three.js

I was wondering if there’s any way to use 3js or a similar javascript-based framework to create a 3D object in virtual space (within the browser window) and have text interact with it — ideally projected onto it, or possibly just hidden or distorted by it in some way.

I’m thinking a virtual version of this type of work by Jenny Holzer, where she projects text onto buildings. The text becomes distorted by the contour of the building and disappears around its contours.
[this is the image I'm referenceing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJMKn.jpg)

Comment: Google "projective texture mapping". It is doable in three.js, but it is not currently supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: If your 3d object has the correct UVs, could it not be done by simply using a dynamic canvas as the map on the 3d objects material? Mush the same way as [this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_canvas) (but with text)